# Saving and Serving static index page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, web

i thought it was simple.. or i might have missed something..  i wanted to save the output of wget and serve it as the index page... but for some reason it always serve the php version instead of the html.

i thought of changing "DirectoryIndex" to serve index.html first.. and restarted apache..

now the issue is when i do wget www.mysite.com/index.php -O index.html it ways serve the HTML version even though i specified index.php

maybe its wordpress related or some misconfig that i did..

tia,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you mean. :/

Do you want to use `wget` to fetch content from other website and serve it within WP?

----- Some type of cache -----

You have to call `wget` using directly the URl of your site, not index.php. For instance:

```
wget -O index.html http://yoursite.com
```

The you get your index.html with its content: css, text, images, js... You might use a redirection rule to serve such file as the default page.

Comment: yes, theoretically.. index.php is currently being loaded initially if someone want to view the site.. 
what i wanted is to use "wget -O index.html www.mysite.com/index.php"
and serve the index.html to users..

and making a background process that runs every 20 secs to re-run wget to refresh index.html

Comment: Mmmm you want to get some type of custom cache.